# Pandas: join two dataframes on semi-overlapping column

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

**Set-up**

Suppose I have two panda DataFrames: `df1`, which is of size `5 x K` and `df2` which is of size `3 x K`,

```
|  key | rest ...             |  key | rest ...
----------------              ----------------
|  A1  |   ⋮                  |  A1  |   ⋮
|  A2  |   ⋮                  |  A3  |   ⋮
|  A3  |   ⋮                  |  A4  |   ⋮
|  A4  |   ⋮
|  A5  |   ⋮
```

In my actual dataset, the `key` contains names (e.g. not `A2`) and the semi-overlap follows no pattern.

---

**Problem**

I want to join `df1` and `df2` on the `key` column, which 'semi-overlaps' in `A1`, `A3` and `A5`.

---

**Plan**

I thought I could add empty rows to `df2`, e.g. two empty rows to `df2` with value `A2` and `A5` for `key`, and subsequently join the DataFrames. However, then I need to figure out which rows are missing in `df2`.

Maybe I can construct a `for` loop over keys, which creates an empty row with for `key` the missing `An` when there is no key match? I'm not sure how to construct a for loop over two dataframes.

Perhaps there is a neat command to join the frames at once, filling in the empty rows?

**EDIT**: Just realised it could be both ways, i.e. that there are keys in `df2` which are not in `df1`. But I suppose running a loop as described first 'checking' keys from `df1` to `df2` and then checking keys from `df2` to `df1` should work.

Comment: Sounds like you want an outer join. Check the Pandas documentation about [Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'semi overlap' join, if you mean keeping unmatched rows from both dataframes in the result, then use `outer merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='outer')
```